# Chaining "is" operators

Tags: python, comparison, operator-keyword, comparison-operators

Does python support chaining `is` operators, such as the following?

```
a = None
b = None
a is b is None
```

This outputs `True`, some doc references would be nice.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Note that you will get different results for comparing identity rather than equality if you move away from singletons and interned integers.

Comment: See my use case, same to that of 1 <= 2 <= 3.

Comment: The answer to the question *"Does python support chaining `is` operators"* is, as demonstrated by your testing, "yes", so I'm wondering what you still want to know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wanted to know the exact semantics.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It’s valid to question behaviour which seems to be valid at the first sight, and seek validation from the docs. Otherwise, bugs might creep in and bad software gets written. So +1 for the question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Any operators classified as comparisons can be chained. From the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Formally, if *a*, *b*, *c*, ..., *y*, *z* are expressions and *op1*, *op2*, ..., *opN*
>   are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent
>   to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

The comparison operators are `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, `<>` (a little-used synonym for `!=`, gone in Python 3), `!=`, `is`, `is not`, `in`, and `not in`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See [comparison docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is)

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
> to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if a, b, c, ..., y, z are expressions and op1, op2, ..., opN
> are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent
> to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
> evaluated at most once.

What the *is* comparison operator does:

> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true
> if and only if x and y are the same object. x is not y yields the
> inverse truth value.

Answer (score 3):

[Referencing the Python grammar documentation](https://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html), which is read by Python to parse source files (so this is the source):

```
comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*
comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'
```

**`expr (comp_op expr)*`** should read, in plain English, "any number of expressions separated by a comparison operator," of which `is` is one. This means that yes, you can chain any number of `is` comparisons together.

To demonstrate that the comparisons are chained:

```
>>> a = b = c = 'foo'
>>> a is b
True
>>> a is b is c
True
>>> True is c
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `is` is a comparison operator, and the formal description of chaining is in the reference manual.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in