# Comparison operators and 'is' - operator precedence in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was looking at some [code](https://github.com/thomasahle/sunfish/blob/88b865a1eb0abc46ad6e658aa60a2e79360bffd4/sunfish.py) online and I came across a line (at line 286):
 `if depth > 0 and best <= -MATE_VALUE is None and nullscore > -MATE_VALUE:`

The part I had trouble understanding was the `best <= -MATE_VALUE is None`. 
So I fired up the interpreter to see how a statement such as `value1 > value2 is value3` work. 
So I tried

```
>>> 5 > 2 is True
False

>>> (5 > 2) is True 
True

>>> 5 > (2 is True) 
True
```

**My Question**
Why is `5 > 2 is True` not `True`? And how do these things generally work? 
Thanks.

Comment: Look up operator chaining. This is actually not a precedence issue. The first is treated logically as `(5 > 2) && (2 is True)`, which is why/how Python allows a meaningful `a < x < b` construct. There are duplicates about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/101945#101945 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103085/chaining-is-operators , http://stackoverflow.com/q/6074018/2864740

Comment: FWIW, this line seems very strange to me -- it's not clear to me when this expression will ever be True.  If MATE_VALUE is a number (which presumably it is because of `-MATE_VALUE`), then it will never be None (if it were, the `-` wouldn't work.)  So if the line doesn't throw an exception, won't it always return False?

Comment: I think the person who wrote that is probably more confused than you are. Neither the actual interpretation (`best <= -MATE_VALUE and -MATE_VALUE is None`) nor either of the plausible incorrect interpretations (`(best <= -MATE_VALUE) is None` or `best <= (-MATE_VALUE is None)`) makes any sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're seeing python's operator chaining working

```
5 > 2 is True
```

Is equivalent to

```
5>2 and 2 is True
```

You can see this in that

```
>>> 5>2 is 2
```

Returns `True`.

Answer (score 3):

First, `5 > 2 is True` is equivalent to `(5 > 2) and (2 is True)` because of operator chaining in python (section 5.9 [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)).

It's clear that `5 > 2` evaluates to True. However, `2 is True` will evaluate to `False` because it is not implicitly converted to `bool`. If you force the conversion, you will find that `bool(2) is True` yields `True`. Other statements such as the `if`-statement will do this conversion for you, so `if 2:` will work.

Second, there is an important difference between the `is` operator and the `==` operator (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)):

> Use `is` when you want to check against an object's identity (e.g.
>   checking to see `if var is None`). Use `==` when you want to check
>   equality (e.g. Is var equal to 3?).

```
>> [1,2] is [1,2]
False

>> [1,2] == [1,2]
True
```

While this does not have an immediate impact on this example, you should keep it in mind for the future.