# Why "True is not False is False"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I evaluate the expression

```
True is not False is False
```

I get True, but I don't understand why. "True is not False" is True, and "True is False" is False, so why do I get True? Indeed, if I use brackets

```
(True is not False) is False
```

I get False.

Comment: Operator chaining...

Comment: `True is not False is False` becomes `(True is not False) and (False is False)` which is `True`.

Comment: The dupe covers the same concept. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103085/chaining-is-operators

Comment: I understand, thanks for the answers! The example `a is b is None` with `a=None` and `b=None` is clear, but my example is weird to understand at first look.